# Repartitioning Android phone's internal memory

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory, partitions

I have a Micromax Unite 2 on Android 4.4.2 KitKat. The original internal memory was 8 GB, but now it shows me only 1.67 GB.

I used a third-party app to see what happened. It shows me unallocated space in 4 different partitions, each one is 700 MB. Other partitions are system, userdata, cache, etc.

Is there any command to do that from the terminal? How to allocate that space?

Comment: I'd better keep my fingers off that unless I'm very firm with the topic (and then I'd not have to ask for "how-to" ;). Changing that partitioning might break future system updates which expect it to be as it is now. Better check with our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Do not attempt to correct this, mine is having the same problem. So, I've started using an SD card. Once I tried to correct this, my phone went dead. Luckily it was under warranty.

If it is partially serviceable, the service centre will figure out that you have used third-party software. Be careful.